# Harvesting from B2Share to GeoNetwork

Tags: metadata, geonetwork, csw

Is there a way to harvest data from the [Eudat B2Share](https://b2share.eudat.eu/) portal in GeoNetwork according to the CSW ISO19139 format?

Currently the only working protocol is from OAI/PMH with prefix oai_dc

Comment: This appears to be a question that should be asked to the administrators of the b2share site, do they expose a CSW endpoint?  It's not really a GeoNetwork question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I asked them too. I just wanted to know if anyone was in a similar situation.

Comment: It should be possible for them to add a CSW service to their CKAN catalogue (pycsw I think is doable), but search as I could I didn't find any evidence of such as service.   I could only find documentation saying they can harvest from CSW.

Comment: But GeoNetwork can harvest from OAI/PMH so if you want ISO metadata you  can just use GeoNetwork to harvest from EDUAT then let GeoNetwork do the conversion...